What solution can I use for edit SQL tables but with some patching of tables already done? like the SELECT JOIN
Hello I'm doing a side project based on mysql for the data part and php for the backend part of visualizing data, javascript and various libs for data representation and so on on the frontend.
The project is basically an advanced dashboard used to monitor various data present on the database.
For the edit part until now I used directly HeidiSQL, a very powerful GUI client.
By having data split between various tables for example:
products:
product_id
product_name
product_kind

sells:
sell_id
product_id
sell_price

and so on
While edit most of things on HeidiSQL is neat and nice, for the part where I have to insert data like sells manually I have to check each time what is the correct product id in the other table.
Would be very nice have a view where I can edit the data and add new one but instead of manually specifying the id I could use the possible products as a menu like an enum where I can read directly the product name.

It seems that I can't use a view in order to edit or add table elements.
A normal approach would be create some php pages in the backend part with some admin privileges and forms, fields, and delete/update/insert SQLs in order to manage the items. In past I did this by reading the data with php, getting a list of product names and relevant ids. Port the data on html with the "select" tag and with options containing the id value.
Given however that I do lot of this mini softwares for my personal uses and that I will be the only one that will edit most of this things, there will be no remote access and so on:

It exists a software that could allow me to do also some basic patching of elements in a table so that I can edit a new line with the product_name directly pointing to a product_id in the sells table?
phpmyadmin have some extra features like that? is something that I can do even with HeidiSQL ? I would avoid to rely on stored procedures on mysql or something similar.
